# Add div id dynamically using jquery to the class element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<div class="leaflet-marker-icon"></div> 
<div class="leaflet-marker-icon"></div> 
<div class="leaflet-marker-icon"></div> 
<div class="leaflet-marker-icon"></div>
```

These are the divs generated by the map and it contains same class
as `leaflet-marker-icon`. For each div I want to add an `id` Attribute with unique Ex (`id=0`, `id=1`, `id=2`, `id=3`);

My code is:

```
var length = $('.leaflet-marker-icon').length;
for (var x = 0; x < length; x++) {
    $('.leaflet-marker-icon').attr('id', x);
}
```

inside for loop it always takes the same id because `$('.leaflet-marker-icon').attr('id', x)` is a class.
Could anybody please suggest how to add unique id to the class.

Comment: how are you adding divs, add id at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

To **continue** your solution : ( *I don't see why people try to show what they know and not correct you*)

try this :

```
var _=$('.leaflet-marker-icon'); //let's cache the array
 var length = _.length; //let's cache the  length
    for(var x=0; x<length; x++) {
        _.eq(x).prop('id', x);
    }
```

sample : http://jsbin.com/vuzuhe/2/edit

Comment: To the point without making many modification to the OP code. Nice answer.

Comment: `_.eq(x).prop('id', x);`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny tnx :-) `x`

Answer (score 1):

Use `:eq` selector inside a for loop.

```
$('.leaflet-marker-icon:eq(' + x + ')').attr('id', x);
```

Answer (score 1):

As your selector is class, so you should know that it returns a collection. So in your case you can just use this:

```
$('.leaflet-marker-icon').attr('id', function(i) {
  return i;
});
```

As you are using jquery and for setting a unique ids for your elements, you can use `.attr('attribute', fn)` for it.

```js
$('.leaflet-marker-icon').attr('id', function(i) {
  return i;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leaflet-marker-icon">leaflet-marker-icon1</div>
<div class="leaflet-marker-icon">leaflet-marker-icon2</div>
<div class="leaflet-marker-icon">leaflet-marker-icon3</div>
<div class="leaflet-marker-icon">leaflet-marker-icon4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rather use `.each()` to iterate over element and use the element context(`this`) to set their attribute value:

```
$('.leaflet-marker-icon').each(function(i){
  this.id=i;
});
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 0):

You should add `id` while adding `div`s dynamically, this will reduce the effort. But if you cannot do this, then try below code

```
var count = 1;
$('.leaflet-marker-icon').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('id',count);
  count++;
});
```

As suggested by Royi Namir, following is another way to achieve your solution

```
$('.leaflet-marker-icon').each(function(i,n){
      $(this).attr('id',i);
 });
```

Comment: you could use `function(i,n)`

Comment: yeah, that is good idea so that I don't have to keep extra variable. let me add it to answer. Thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable and set it to zero. Using, `each()` function, add an `id` attribute equal to this variable and increase the variable by one in order to be assigned to the next element.

Inspect the div elements for results:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //var i = 0;
  $('.leaflet-marker-icon').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', i);
    //i++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leaflet-marker-icon">1</div> 
 <div class="leaflet-marker-icon">2</div> 
 <div class="leaflet-marker-icon">3</div> 
<div class="leaflet-marker-icon">4</div>
```

Comment: you could use `function(i,n)`